# CSS check-up tool

Tags: css

I was wondering if the [CSS Usage add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) for Firefox FireBUG checks the whole website for cross-used CSS rules and styles or does it check only the page that you are currently on and scanning?

What I mean by this > If I remove the styles marked as "unused" and they are referring to inner pages, that would ruin the website I am working on since it is not a one-page site. Does it scan all the pages or only the current page I am viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the description begins with

> CSS Coverage is an extension for Firebug which allows you to scan multiple pages of your site to see which CSS rules are actually used in your site.

Each page is scanned separately and manually. So it is not a very usefull extension.

Answer (score 3):

**How does it work?**

- Open up the first page of the site you want to check and press the "Scan" button in the "CSS Coverage" Firebug tab.
- In case of a rich (Ajax or DHTML) site, open up as many divs/popups/tabs in the page as possible and press "Scan" again.
- Visit other pages of your site and press "Scan" again.

Copying it from the **About This Addon** section of the link you've given, it's clearly obvious you have to scan each page separately....
, perhaps you may wanna try reading some other places before sending a question.

Comment: Actually I did read that.

So I asked a very specific question. I have ONE css file for all my pages. In other words - what is good for one of the pages might not be good for the other pages in the eyes of this scan tool.

Comment: Then you better not use the tool, since every page you will be scanning is rooting from the same CSS properties....

Answer (score 1):

As **[Neophyte Polyhistor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180309/neophyte-polyhistor)** and **[Vann'Tile Ianito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679160/vanntile-ianito)** said - this add-on for Firebug does scan ONLY the page you are currently viewing.

I found another tool that seems to do the task that I was after. It is called [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/). It seems to scan the whole site and all the files linked to it.

This solved my problem described in the first post. I hope it helps someone else in time.

Thanks!